# In const a = b => b([ { var: "foo" }, { var: "baz" } ]); is b a function, array, or variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, parentheses

I am reading the following code in a react tutorial.

```
const a = b =>
  b([
    { var: "foo" },
    { var: "baz" }
  ]);
```

I understand there is an array with a list of objects inside, but what does the () parenthesis mean here?

Comment: It must be a function (or proxy), else it'd result in an error

Comment: ^^ you're calling the `b` function by using parenthesis `()`

Comment: would there be a article I could read up on this more about? I'm still confused how a function is passed down as a variable.

Comment: This is similar to `function a(b) { b([.....]); }` but the context is kept (and some other differences) because `a` is defined as an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in JavaScript are [first-class citizens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function). This means that you can treat a function just like any other variable. This allows you to do things such as assigning them to other variables etc...:

```js
const foo = arg => arg;
const also_foo = foo;

console.log(also_foo("hello"));
```

With this in mind, you can also pass them into functions, just like you can with regular variables. For instance:

```js
const foo = arg => arg; // foo simply just returns the argument it is given
const bar = foo_function => foo_function('bar'); // use `foo` in `bar` function

console.log(bar(foo)); // pass reference of `foo` to `bar`.
```

Here, we pass a reference of the `foo` function into the `bar` function. This allows the function `bar()` to use the `foo` function by calling `foo_function('bar')`.

This sort of pattern is very common in JS, especially with callbacks (here is an example using setTimeout):

```js
const foo = () => console.log("a");
setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

If you can image implementing `setTimeout` yourself, it would *loosely* look something along the lines of this:

```
const setTimeout = (func, time) => {
  // wait `time` miliseconds
  // execute func
  func();
}
```

Many other functions use callbacks, such as high-order array functions. Whilst you don't need to implement the logic of these yourself, you can see how you could make your own function which executes a callback.

> but what does the () parenthesis mean here

So, to answer your question. If `b` is a function, then the `()` invoke/call the function `b`. The list of objects is what is being passed through into the function `b`.

Answer (score 2):

The above code shows a function which takes another function as a parameter. Arrow function makes it little confusing. The `()` is calling the function `b`

Without arrow function it will look like

```
function a(b){
   return b([
    { var: "foo" },
    { var: "baz" }
  ])
}
```

A demo is shown in below snippet.

```js
const a = b =>
  b([
    { var: "foo" },
    { var: "baz" }
  ]);


const addProp = (array) => array.map(x => ({...x, newProp: "New Value"}));

console.log(a(addProp))
```